# Python function capturing variable

Tags: python, function

I am beginning to code with Python. I have run into this problem. I am searching for a string in my file handle variable by creating a function for that. However, every time I iterate through the lines in the file handle variable and pass it on to the function, the variable I use for count in the function initializes with 0. Is there a way through to capture the number of times a string appears in a file, by defining a function instead of counting in the main program?

```
def func(a): 
    c=0
    a=a.strip()
    if "Temp" in a:
        c+=1
    return c

fhand=open("file_address")

for i in fhand:
    print(func(i))
```

Comment: Please put a [mre], **as text**, in the question itself.

Comment: Do you understand what `for i in fhand:` is doing? Do you understand what `if "Temp" in a:` is doing? Your function is basically returning 0 or 1 depending if `"Temp"` was in a specific line of the file (what if it occurs more than 1 time?). Each call doesn't know what happened with the other lines. Why not just pass the file to the function, or not use a function at all? It is not clear what is your expected output (and what is your input) and with what exactly you are struggling

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to do all the counting, you can put the whole loop into the function. Then use the [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method to get the number of "Temp"s in each line:

```
def func(fhand):
    c=0
    for a in fhand:
        c += a.count('Temp')
    return c

fhand=open("file_address")

print(func(fhand))
```